# Problemas com threads em C++

Tags: c++, thread, multithreading, mingw

Olá, eu estou a usar o mingw, versão 32-bits no windows 7 Ultimate e estou com problemas a utilizar threads.
Eu sei que não funcionam para esta versão do mingw, razão pela qual uso a versão neste [link](https://github.com/meganz/mingw-std-threads). Mas eu não compila este exemplo, porque diz que

> In static member function 'static unsigned int mingw_stdthread::thread::_hardware_concurrency_helper()':
>   error: '::GetNativeSystemInfo' has not been declared (in line 266)

Isto no ficheiro thread que fiz download, testei [neste site e funcionou este exemplo](http://cpp.sh/8yxm), alguém me poderia dizer o porquê de isto acontecer?

```
#include <iostream>         // std::cout
#include <thread>           // std::thread

class test {
public:
    static void foo(){}
    static void bar(int x){}
    test(){
         std::thread first (foo);     // spawn new thread that calls foo()
         std::thread second (bar,0);  // spawn new thread that calls bar(0)
         first.join();                // pauses until first finishes
         second.join();               // pauses until second finishes
    }
};

int main() {
     test TESTE;
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: herm.. E qual o problema?

Comment: @Kahler editei o post.

Comment: Quais foram as flags/bandeiras que você passou pro mingw?

Comment: [Problema parecido](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28036686/use-pthreads-in-mingw-in-win7).

Comment: @MárioFeroldi Eu não passei nenhuma flag e já tentei com a tag -pthread, sem sucesso, e já tinha encontrado esse post quando andei á procura da resposta.

Comment: @Simplecoder eu ajustei o link que você forneceu para conter o seu código exemplo (vai aparecer quando algum editor aprovar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existem muitas distribuições diferentes do Mingw, algumas não suportam threads diretamente e requerem inclusão de código específico da plataforma. A página que você postou contém esses pedaços de código, embora o autor declare que só testou para o MinGW-w64 5.3.0, e avisa que os macros para detecção de plataforma podem [ter de ser ajustados manualmente](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/modifying-winver-and-win32-winnt) para algumas versões do Windows.

O erro que você postou é relacionado com uma declaração faltante, você incluiu a biblioteca requerida de acordo com as instruções?

> This is a header-only library. To use, just include the corresponding mingw.xxx.h file, where xxx would be the name of the standard header that you would normally include.

Talvez você precise declarar, no código em sua plataforma:

```
#include mingw.thread.h
#include <thread>
```

Caso não seja esse o problema, e você esteja disposto e apto a usar outra distribuição para Windows, que já contenha threads embutidos (recomendo), aqui estão algumas opções abertas:

- [TDM GCC](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/download), vem com a versão GCC 5.1.0 (muito fácil de instalar e usar)
- [Mingw-w64](https://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/start), vem com o GCC 7.3

Comment: Continua a não funcionar, diz _fatal error: mingw.thread.h: No such file or directory_.

Comment: Bem, se você traduzir esse erro para o português: "mingw.thread.h: Arquivo ou diretório inexistente", o que quer dizer que você não adicionou os arquivos durante a sua compilação, ou forneceu caminho errado...